# How to change materials and textures in autodesk-forge with the same quality?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Im working with NWC models translated into SVG and i need to change the materials/textures from it. I created my own custom materiales with textures with MeshPhongMaterial but the result isnt the same because the quality is bad, i just need to replace the img texture of that material. Could you tell me what is the correct way of doing this? Thank you.

Is there any example of changing materials/textures in autodesk-forge that you con provide me?

Answer (score 0):

Materials coming from SVF can be quite complex, with varying schemas. For example, the carbon fiber material in the screenshot below is loaded as a `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with many custom properties such as `layered_anisotropy`, `layered_bottom_f0`, `layered_bottom_f0_map`, or `layered_diffuse`.

[image]

Because of that, customization of textures of SVF materials would be very difficult unfortunately.

If the quality of the custom `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` is not sufficient, I'd suggest tweaking some of its parameters, for example, adding an [environment map](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.envMap) (see an [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_envmaps.html)).